# BSOD 90% of the time during a TrueCrypt mount

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, bsod

About 90% of the time when I mount a TrueCrypt share I get a blue screen of death. The error codes I see in the BSOD vary. The last two I saw mentioned eamon.sys and irql_less_than_or_equal.

- Windows 7 Professional
- TrueCrypt 7.0a
- ESET NOD32 AV
- I am not using the EXT2 driver

Googling didn't turn up much, but hinted at TueCrypt + NOD32 issues. I tried disabling NOD32 real time monitoring during mounts, but it didn't help. How can I determine the cause?

Comment: Have you tried disabling NOD32? Being that eamon is part of NOD32, I would try disabling it and see if it stops the BSOD. If so, maybe check to see if there is an update for NOD32 or open a ticket with them. A google search returns LOTS of BSOD issues in Win7 with NOD32.

Comment: I did, and it didn't help. At this point I'm about ready to move to Mac. Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATE: The problem reoccurred; this didn't fix the issue.*

Disabling NOD32 didn't help. The solution was to set the exe of TrueCrypt to Windows Vista SP2 compatibility.

1. Go to the installation folder for TrueCrypt

   > C:\Program Files (x86)\TrueCrypt
2. Right click TrueCrypt.exe
3. Go to the Compatibility tab
4. Check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:"
5. Set it to Windows Vista SP2

Comment: Good on you for coming back and posting your solution (correctly as well) after an extended period of time :)

Comment: @Mark - Thanks! But of course, after it not happening many times, I posted this answer and it BSOD'ed earlier today. Ugh.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an on-going issue.  Please check the official support forums for further information.

A couple of posts indicate that by doing this, it may resolve your issues:

1. Disable boot sector scanning OR
2. Deactivating "Automatic startup file check" under schedule

[wilders](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=280305&highlight=eset%20nod32%20truecrypt)